# Why my self-define signal handler will make child process get SIGTTIN when comparing pid

Tags: c++, c, multiprocessing, signals

I writing a simple shell.
To deal with zombie processes, I use `signal(SIGHLD, signal_handler)` and a self-define hadler.

When I run this program in some way, gdb will tell me child received `SIGTTIN` and program stopped.
But if I change my handler to `while(waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)>0);`, everything goes perfectly.

I wonder why this change will cause the error. After some google, It's seems to relate with "child process' signal handler.
However, this handler never tries to read from stdin or something like that.

Can anyone tell me why this will happen and how this works?
Or give me some key words to search.
Thank for your helps!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

int parse_argv(stringstream &in_command, char** &argv);   //get argv list
void sig_handle(int sig);

int main()
{

    while(true){
        string input, output;
        stringstream ss;

        char **myArgv;
        int myArgc;
        bool back_ground = false;
        cout << ">";

        getline(cin, input);
        ss << input;

        myArgc = parse_argv(ss, myArgv);    //get argument!
        if(strcmp(myArgv[myArgc-1], "&") == 0){        //check if & exit
            back_ground = true;
            myArgv[myArgc-1] = NULL;
        }
        pid_t pid = fork();


        if(pid < 0){
            cout << "Fork process error!" << endl;
        }
        else if(pid == 0){ //child process
            execvp(myArgv[0], myArgv);

            exit(0);
        }
        else{    //parent process
            if(back_ground == false)
                wait(&pid);
            else
                signal(SIGCHLD, sig_handle);
                                             //Free memory!!
            for(int i=0; i<=myArgc; i++)     //size of myArgv is myArgc+1
                delete[] myArgv[i];
            delete[] myArgv;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int parse_argv(stringstream &in_command, char** &argv){
    vector<string> tmp;
    string tmp_s;

    tmp.reserve(10);

    while(in_command >> tmp_s){
        tmp.push_back(tmp_s);
    }

    argv = new char* [tmp.size()+1];        //dynamic allocate true arugments array
    for(int i=0; i<tmp.size(); i++){
        argv[i] = new char[strlen(tmp[i].c_str())];
        strcpy(argv[i], tmp[i].c_str());
    }
    argv[tmp.size()] = NULL;                //argv should terminated by NULL
    return tmp.size();
}

void sig_handle(int sig){
    int status;
    while(waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG));
}
```

How to repeat error:

1. Compile and run this program
2. Type `ls &[Enter]`
3. Type `ls[Enter]`
4. Then you will find the second `ls` does not return anything. In gdb, you will see child process get SIGTTIN in line:38.

My Enviroment is Ubuntu 18.04 with bash & g++

[image: gdb image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your SIGTTIN error with the code you provided, and that might just be due to the exact sequence of gdb commands you used, but your program did become unresponsive after I gave it the following input:

```
ls &
ls
```

gdb showed that this `while` statement was in an infinite loop:

```
void sig_handle(int sig){
    int status;
    while(waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG));
}
```

Adding a printf to get a closer look<sup>1</sup>:

```
void sig_handle(int sig){
    int status, i, r;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        errno = 0;
        r = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
        printf("waitpid returns %d errno %d\n", r, errno);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
waitpid returns 3672 errno 0
waitpid returns -1 errno 10
waitpid returns -1 errno 10
waitpid returns -1 errno 10
waitpid returns -1 errno 10
```

So the logic ought to be changed so that the loop terminates when either the process has been waited for or there are no processes to wait for (or some other error that won't go away just by calling `waitpid` again). The [man page for waitpid](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man2/wait.2.html)
says:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> on  success,  returns  the process ID of the child whose state has changed; if WNOHANG was specified and one or more child(ren) specified by pid exist, but have not yet changed state, then 0 is returned.  On error, -1 is returned.
>
> ERRORS
>
> ECHILD The process specified by pid does not exist or is not a child of the calling process.
>
> EINTR  WNOHANG was not set and an unblocked signal or a SIGCHLD was caught.
>
> EINVAL The options argument was invalid.

So I would change the code to:

```
void sig_handle(int sig){
    int status;

    while (waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG) == 0); // more precisely, break if r > 0 || r == -1
}
```

<sup>1</sup>: printf in a signal handler is a Bad Thing(TM), but it's usually OK for debugging.